# run stored procedure and return values from VBA

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, excel, vba

I would like to pass parameters into a stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 and I would like to store the results in a `ADODB.Recordset`

Currently I have this:

```
Public Sub UpdateWithStoredProcedure()
        Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
        Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
        Dim prm As ADODB.Parameter
        Dim strConn As String
        Dim strSQL As String

        strConn = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;" & _
            "Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=NorthWind;" & _
            "Integrated Security=SSPI"

        Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
        conn.Open strConn

        Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
        cmd.CommandText = "procOrderUpdate"
        cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        cmd.ActiveConnection = conn

        Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("OrderID", adInteger, adParamInput)
        cmd.Parameters.Append prm
        cmd.Parameters("OrderID").Value = 1

        Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("OrderDate", adDate, adParamInput)
        cmd.Parameters.Append prm
        cmd.Parameters("OrderDate").Value = "1/1/2007"

        Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("ShipVia", adInteger, adParamInput)
        cmd.Parameters.Append prm
        cmd.Parameters("ShipVia").Value = 2
        Set prm = cmd.CreateParameter("Freight", adCurrency, adParamInput)
        cmd.Parameters.Append prm
        cmd.Parameters("Freight").Value = "10.5"

        'Execute the Stored Procedure
        cmd.Execute

        'Close the connection
        conn.Close
    End Sub
```

The question is how do I store this in a recordset instead of just executing it?

Comment: Is your stored procedure written to return a record set?

Comment: @tim im sorry can you please explain the difference between a stored procedure returning a recordset and the alternative?

Comment: Not all stored procedures are designed to return a record set.  Some stored procedures just pass back information via "out" parameters. Did you try Pynner's suggestion?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I believe all you need is this

```
Dim Rst As ADODB.Recordset
```

and this

```
Set Rst = cmd.Execute
```