# Executing a SQL stored procedure with parameters in VBA

Tags: stored-procedures, excel, vba

I'm fairly new to this. I'm trying to write a procedure in VBA that executes a stored procedure from excel and returns the record set. It currently returns the results of the stored procedure in spreadsheet 2 but I've had to hard code the parameter into the SQL code. Here is what I have pinched from other online forums.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub OpenConnection()

'Set the variables
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim str As String
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim fld
Dim i As Integer

'Error handler
On Error GoTo errlbl

'Open database connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

'First, construct the connection string.

'ODBC CONNECTION YOU'VE ALREADY SET UP:
conn.ConnectionString = "DSN=PC_Tool_Coding"

conn.Open       'Here's where the connection is opened.

Debug.Print conn.ConnectionString  'This can be very handy to help debug!

'Recordset
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset

str = "exec Select_account_info"

'recordset is opened here
rs.Open str, conn, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

If Not IsEmptyRecordset(rs) Then
    rs.MoveFirst

    'Populate the first row of the sheet with recordset’s field names
    i = 0
    For Each fld In rs.Fields
        Sheet2.Cells(1, i + 1).Value = rs.Fields.Item(i).Name
        i = i + 1
    Next fld
    'Populate the sheet with the data from the recordset
    Sheet2.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs


Else
    MsgBox "Unable to open recordset, or unable to connect to database.", _
       vbCritical, "Can't get requested records"

End If

'Cleanup
rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
conn.Close
Set conn = Nothing

exitlbl:
  Debug.Print "Error: " & Err.Number
  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    MsgBox "Done", vbOKOnly, "All Done."
  End If
  Exit Sub
errlbl:
   MsgBox "Error #: " & Err.Number & ", Description:  " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Error in OpenConnection()"
Exit Sub
'Resume exitlbl
End Sub
```

I've looked around on how to get it to work with parameters and I just can't seem to get there. The parameter I'll be using is called @accgrpnum in SQL. Its a 12 letter string.

Many thanks to any help in advance.

Comment: What database vendor are you using? (i.e. MS SQL, MySQL, DB2, etc.)

Comment: Have you taken a look at [run a parametrized SQL stores procedure in vba](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249706/run-stored-procedure-and-return-values-from-vba) and all similar questions on your right hand side? On mobile, else would have given your a code a boost.

Comment: Hall.stephenk : it looks more like connecting to access or excel itself on a temp DB style

Comment: I am using SQL server Management Studio.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at bonCodigo's link or

I've also been able to do this (with SQL Server 2008) by sending more than one statement, but separated in a SQL statement like

```
str = "SET @accgrpnum = 'my_account'; exec Select_account_info;"
```