# Excel VBA passing wrong number of parameters to ADO command object

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I am trying to debug Excel VBA code that is calling a stored procedure resident on our SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 R2). With a bit of error trapping I can now see what the error is but I have no idea what is causing it.

Here is my VBA code:

```
Sub Add_Results_Of_ADO_Recordset()

Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim stSQL As String

Const stADO As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;User ID =xxxxx;Password=xxxxx;" & _
"Persist Security Info=False;" & _
"Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;" & _
"Data Source=xxxxxxxxxxxx"

' initialise ADO
Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
cnt.Open stADO

On Error GoTo Err_SaveProposal

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = cnt
    .CommandText = "PolicyList"
    .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
    .NamedParameters = True
    .Parameters.Refresh
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Incept", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, "2/1/2014")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@Expire", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, "2/1/2014")
    .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@PStatus", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, "BOOK")
End With

' Debug code to ensure parameters are set correctly
For Each prm In cmd.Parameters
    Debug.Print prm.Name & " : " & prm.Value
Next

cmd.Execute


If cnt.State = adStateOpen Then cnt.Close
Exit Sub

Err_SaveProposal:
  Debug.Print Err.Number & ": " & Err.Description

If cnt.State = adStateOpen Then cnt.Close


End Sub
```

Here are the messages written to the immediate window:

```
@RETURN_VALUE : 
@Incept : 
@Expire : 
@PStatus : 
@Incept : 2/1/2014
@Expire : 2/1/2014
@PStatus : BOOK
-2147217900: Procedure or function PolicyList has too many arguments specified.
```

It looks like the three arguments I am trying to send to the stored procedure are being sent twice. Once as empty strings and one with the values I want to send. Any suggestions?

Comment: I get `@Incept : 2/1/2014` `@Expire : 2/1/2014` `@PStatus : BOOK`. Also can you print out your parameters to the immediate window after you `.Refresh` but before you `Append` anything? What happens when you open the connection on the line before you execute instead of before the parameters are appended?

Comment: Did you try to execute the SP manually by passing these three parameters ?

Comment: @Santosh In my original code I tried to execute the SP using this statement: cnt.Execute "PolicyList " & "'2/1/2014'" & ", " & "'2/1/2014'" & ", " & "'BOOK'". I got the same error error that too many parameters were being specified. After trying to debug for several days I ended out trying to define parameters in the code above thinking it would give me more control. No such luck.

Comment: @Brad I cut and pasted the lines of code initializing the ADO connection to just before the cmd.Execute statement. It solved my duplicate problem but apparently the connection is bad. The lines in the immediate window are: 
'@Incept : 2/1/2014'
'@Expire : 2/1/2014'
'@PStatus : BOOK'
3709: The connection cannot be used to perform this operation. It is either closed or invalid in this context.

Comment: That is printed out to the immediate window? Is that printed when you try to access the parameters or when you try to execute?

Comment: @Brad it is printed out when I try to execute.

Comment: Is it actually open? can you look at the status in the locals window? Are your parameters to your stored proc `@Incept` and `@Expire` actually varchars or are they dates?

Comment: @Brad I checked and "adStateOpen = 1" so I think that the connection is open. In the stored procedure the parameters are defined as: '@Incept' NVARCHAR(10), '@Expire' NVARCHAR(10), '@PStatus' VARCHAR(20)). I convert to dates in the WHERE clause of the query.

Comment: @Brad I found a bug in my code and it appears that the SP is now receiving the correct parameters and the connection is open but no recordset is being returned.

Comment: Are you setting it to a recordset? in your example in your question you are just doing `cmd.Execute` not `dim rst as ADODB.Recordset:set rst = cmd.Execute`

Comment: @Brad I added code to populate the recordset exactly like you show once the other errors cleared up. I don't know why no records are being returned (the same query submitted in SQL Server Management Studio returns 279 records).

Comment: How are you check that there are no records? What kind of object is your stored procedure? Is it actually a procedure (can only return scalar values) or is it a Table Valued Function (can actually return a table)?

Comment: @Brad It is a stored procedure that returns records from a query. The same SP when ran in SQL Server Management Studio returns 276 records. When I type "?rst.fields(0)" into the immediate window I get an error message that basically tells me there are no records in the recordset.

Comment: You need to use a Table Value function. Just because you have a Select somewhere in your SP that is dumping records to the result pane does not mean your SP is returning records. Try doing `Select * from PolicyList where somecolumn = 'blah'`. Does it work?

Comment: @Brad Thank you for the tip. I just ran a SQL trace and the SP is receiving the correct number of parameters and is executing. I do probably need to run a Table Value function.

Comment: @Brad I have one last question. With your help I have corrected my VBA code and I can prove that the stored procedure is running on the SQL Server (I ran a SQL trace and could watch it execute). According to all of the documentation I can find the records resulting from the SP execution should be returned to the Excel recordset. Can you refer me to any article that deals with this kind of issue?