# VB6 Database Closed Error on Execution of Stored Procedure when Create Table or Select Into in procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb6, adodb

I have an application that I'm modifying. Originally, there was a giant brick of in line SQL that executed to return some data. Due to requests for changes, I've put that into a stored procedure that does more than just return data, and am now trying to execute. Here is the code that I cannot get to work:

```
 Dim oConnCRS as CRS_Connection
 Dim sSQL As String
 Dim oRS_ReturnRecs As ADODB.Recordset

 sSQL = "EXECUTE dbo.StoredProcedure @StartDate = '" & dStartDate & "', @EndDate ='" & dEndDate & "'"

 Set oConnCRS = New CRS_Connection
 Set oRS_ReturnRecs = New ADODB.Recordset

 With oRS_ReturnRecs
 .Open sSQL, oConnCRS.Connection, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

 If .EOF Then
    .Close
    Me.MousePointer = vbDefault
    MsgBox "No return file activity to report", vbExclamation + vbOKOnly, APP_NAME

    Exit Sub
 End If
```

If I change the sSQL to something like "Select Column from Table Where Condition" it will work just fine.

The stored procedure is loading a bunch of information into a temporary table, modifying it, and then selecting all of the records from the temporary table.

I have tried changing various settings on the with open, but I still get an error on

```
 If .EOF then
```

The error is: "Operation is not allowed when Object is closed"

CRS_Connection is a object that contains all of the connection information for the database, and on a new instantiation opens the connection automatically.

Any guidance or suggestions on what we're doing wrong is greatly appreciated.

---

New Discovery:

I started having this problem again on another application. I create a temp table, fill it with data, and then select from it. When I do that, I get the same closed error I was experiencing before.

When I remove the select into or create table, it executes without a problem.

What about creating temp tables in stored procedures causes VB6 to close the connection? Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: please paste sSQL var contents *after* concatenation of dates. I'm not familiar with MSSQL, but I guess the dates should be passed as #mm-dd-yyyy# instead of quotes.

Comment: Not sure how your code will work when you change to `Select column from table where condition`. You seem to be missing connection string and opening the connection in your code. Have you pasted the full code or just part of it?

Comment: Edited to proper tag, it's MSSQL 2008

Comment: CRS_Connection is a object that contains all of the connection information for the database, and on a new instantiation opens the connection automatically.

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea where this error is coming from, or why it works with a regular 'Select * from xxx' but not 'exec storedproc'

Comment: Not sure if the way you have it can return a recordset, even though it can invoke a stored procedure to do processing (insert, update, etc). The examples I've seen use a command object. [Example 1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676516(v=vs.85).aspx), [Example 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8249706/run-stored-procedure-and-return-values-from-vba)

Comment: can you paste here the command *after* the concatenation with the contents of dStartDate & dEndDate? have you tried with #mm-dd-yyyy# ?

Comment: (EXECUTE dbo.StoredProc @@StartDate = '8/22/2014', @@EndDate ='8/28/2014'). When I run this directly in SSMS it returns the info without any problems. I had to put @@ instead of a single one because it was trying to tag users.

Comment: try sending this via VB: "EXECUTE dbo.StoredProc @StartDate = '2014-08-22', @EndDate='2014-08-28'". See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180878(v=sql.100).aspx#StringLiteralDateandTimeFormats

Comment: Two things to try. Have you checked the connection error object after the Open call? Have you tried making a very simple stored proc such as SELECT Column FROM Table and see if you can execute that?

Comment: In your code, try changing adCmdText to adCmdStoredProc,

Comment: Changed it to adCmdStoredProc and I get nothing, I created a basic stored procedure as suggested and it doesn't work either. I said forget it and just rewrote the entire project in .net instead of VB6. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem to what you are describing.

Adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the start of the stored procedure solved the problem for me.

Some more suggestions in case this does not solve the problem :
http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/414056/VB-Recordset-not-opening-with-stored-procedure